# How can I put an answerline before the number of the questions in an exam class?

Tags: exam

Our exams are usually in this [form](https://ibb.co/h0dQFa) (don't mind the border lines), where the answer line is before the number. In the `exam` document class, however, I can't do it. Putting `\answerline` before `\question` can't be done, because an error arises (from TexStudio):

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \answerline \question...
```

I also tried putting `\makebox[0.1\textwidth]{\hrulefill}` before `\question` to have a line before the number, and it gives much less the same error:

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \makebox[0.1\textwidth]{\hrulefill} \question...
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question He believed that matter consists of four elements of air, earth, water, and fire.
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your format is consistent through the exam, you can redefine the `\questionlabel` macro with something like this:

```
\renewcommand\questionlabel{\rule{2cm}{1pt} \thequestion.}
```

With this in the preamble of your MWE, you get:

[image: rendering]